# Determine if a key is shifted with Python-xlib

Tags: python, xlib

I'm using `python-xlib` to generate some key press events. In order to do this I need to determine if a particular character (say 'A') needs a shift mask or not.

The C `XLib` defines a method called [`XConvertCase`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/XConvertCase.html) that can be used for this purpose. However, I can't see anything similar in `python-xlib`.

Currently I have the following, which is terrible:

```
if key in '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?><' or key.isupper():
    # key needs shifting...
```

What's the best way to determine if a given character needs a shift mask

Comment: Regardless of how you solve this, keep in mind that different keyboard layouts around the World have different positions for a lot of symbols. (On my keyboard, right now, the character laying where your `~` is is `"` (double quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Some sample code is here: http://shallowsky.com/software/crikey/pykey-0.1, however it uses just about the same code you described as "terrible".

Here's another way, can't say it's "better", just "different". I don't really know what I'm doing, this is based on some study plus some experimentation and could very well be fatally flawed:

```
>>> import Xlib
>>> import Xlib.display
>>> display = Xlib.display.Display()
Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension
>>> m = display._keymap_codes
>>> unshifted = [k[0] for k in m if k]
>>> shifted = [k[1] for k in m if k]
>>> ord('[') in shifted
False
>>> ord('?') in shifted
True
>>> ord('}') in shifted
True
>>> ord('/') in shifted
False
```

You could also use Display.get_keyboard_mapping instead of _keymap_codes, but then you'd need to pass it the right parameters, and the documentation is a bit too obscure for my ability to follow.